# Не могу получить данные из sqlite таблицы

Tags: python, sqlite, aiogram

пишу:

```
post = cur.execute("""SELECT id FROM ochered""")
print(post)
```

получаю:

```
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000000003E0FB20>
```

весь код:

```
import config
import json

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import sqlite3 as sq
import asyncio
import aioschedule

bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

global base, cur
base = sq.connect('ochered.db')
cur = base.cursor()

async def on_startup(_):
    scheduler()
    
async def scheduler():
    aioschedule.every(1).minutes.do(public)
    while True:
        await aioschedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo', 'video'])
async def dobavlenie(message: types.Message):
    base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ochered(id, type)')
    if message.photo:
        params = ( message.photo[0].file_id, 'photo')
    elif message.video:
        params = ( message.video.file_id, 'video')
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO ochered VALUES (?, ?)', params)
    base.commit()
    
#@dp.message_handler()
async def dobavlenie(message: types.Message):
    chmo = cur.fetchone()
    print(chmo)

@dp.message_handler()
async def public(message: types.Message):
    post = cur.execute("""SELECT id FROM ochered""")
    print(post)
    #await bot.send_photo( chat_id = config.chat_id, photo = post[0])
    #cur.execute('DELETE id FROM ochered WHERE ROW_NOMBER == 1')
executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

потому что после execute нужно выбирать значения через fetch, если комманда должна была что-то вернуть.

```
post = cur.execute("""SELECT id FROM ochered""")
print(post.fetchall())
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: спасибо! помогло